# Assigning Columnnames dynamically

Tags: r, attributes, spatial, rgdal

I have an interesting problem:

I need to batchprocess a few files. I do that in a for-loop, where some operations are performed. Later on I want to write the outcome into an existing shapefile which I do like so:

```
myShapeFile@data <- data.frame(myShapeFile@data,  dynamicColumnName = VALUE)
```

The `dynamicColumnName` gets created dynamically - depending what statistic is performed and so on. Meaning: The name is stored in the variable.
So `dynamicColumnName` could be "2245", in the next iteration of the loop or "0000" or "3334" and so on.

However, the function above does not accept the "characters/integers" stored in the variable. Each column gets named `dynamicColumnName`.

Any ideas how to not let this happen?

Comment: `myShapeFile@data[, dynamicColumnName] <- value`

Comment: @Roland `Can't convert columns of class: matrix; column names: 0000, 3334 ` is my result  when i try `writeOGR` then.

Comment: Well, make sure that `VALUE` is not a matrix, but a vector I guess ...

Comment: @Roland It is `chracater`, thats what `typeof()` gives me

Comment: Check the `class`.

Comment: @Roland `dynamicColumnName` is a `character` while `value` is a `matrix`

Comment: And that's what the error is complaining about. Assuming you have a one-column matrix, you can use `myShapeFile@data[, dynamicColumnName] <- c(value)`